# Handsontable remove settings [especially width and height]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, handsontable

I am working with **handsontable** [JavaScript Spreadsheet
library] and want to toggle settings with a bootstrap-styled-checkbox. The first thing was, to set a specific width and height to the table when the box is checked and to undo this fixed size (so it automatically resizes again) when uncheck the box.
Here is my current code:

```
$('#mycheckbox').click(function() {
  if($('#mycheckbox').prop("checked") == true){
    handsontable_table.updateSettings({
       width: 725,
       height:100
    })
  }else{
  handsontable_table.updateSettings({
        // missing :(

        //UPDATE:
         width: null,
         height: null
  })
 }
});
```

At first, my handsontable-table is automatically sized to the correct size. When I check the checkbox, the table resizes to the given width and height. But I don't know how to remove this width- and height-settings. I tried to set them to 'false' or 0 or remove these settings with jQuery-.removeProp(), but none of them does what I want. And I can't find something right in the handsontable-docs (or other sites).

I very appreciate your help!

**EDIT**

I found a solution: You just have to set the width and height to `null`. See edit above.
But there is something strange going on when I minimize my table and maximize it again - at first, my div below the table slides up to the new bottom of my table, but when it gets big again, the div doesn't move anymore, its overlapping with the table...

However, I still don't know how to remove settings from a handsontable...

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your edit, by updating the value to null it appears to be one way to reset a setting with in Handsontables options. It my experience you do not want to set the height and width to null, but instead update it to a new value.

If you were clearing out a setting like nestedHeaders for example; you would just set the value to null to stop using the nestedHeaders feature. However, that doesn't work for every option.

If you are trying to expand and collapse a handsontable then setting the height and width to null or zero is not going to be the best solution. You should update the parent div to display null using jQuery(handsontable's parent selector).hide() or .show().